# insert blank row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code which is bound to the @Html.DropDownListFor :

**ViewModel**

```
    public static UserManagementViewModel CreateCompanyMappingViewModel(List<Company> company)
    {
        UserManagementViewModel viewModel = new UserManagementViewModel();
        viewModel.Companies = new SelectList(company, "CompanyID", "CompanyName");
        return viewModel;
    }
}
```

**cshtml**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyID, Model.Companies, new { style = "width:300px;" })
```

The dropdownlist is bound successfully. What I need is, to insert a blank row to the DropDownList and get it selected first, while binding to the DropDownList. How ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [following overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703670%28v=vs.108%29):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.CompanyID, 
    Model.Companies, 
    "-- select a company --", 
    new { style = "width:300px;" }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Html.DropDownListFor(model  => model.CompanyID, Model.Companies, " ", new { style = "width:300px;" })